# Internal server error 500 only on request with larger amounts of data in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have the following Azure Function:

```
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        GetForumTopicsResponseModel forumTopicsModel = new GetForumTopicsResponseModel();
        try
        {
            HtpaaForumDB.HtpaaForumDB forumDB = new HtpaaForumDB.HtpaaForumDB(context);
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            GetForumTopicsTokenRequestModel reqMod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetForumTopicsTokenRequestModel>(requestBody);

            log.LogInformation("index:" + reqMod.IndexStart + " count:" + reqMod.Count);
            List<Topic> topics = await forumDB.GetTopics(reqMod.SortOrder, reqMod.IndexStart, reqMod.Count);
            log.LogInformation("Count:" + topics.Count);
            forumTopicsModel.Topics = topics;
            forumTopicsModel.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogCritical(ex,"Error");
            forumTopicsModel.Message = ex.Message;
            forumTopicsModel.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
        return new ObjectResult(forumTopicsModel);
```

Everythings works as expected when I request 2 forumtopics, but gives me an error 500 if I request more. The log seems to indicate that things goes as planned inside the function:

```
2020-11-23T12:17:00.716 [Information] Executing 'GetForumTopics' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.')
2020-11-23T12:17:00.758 [Information] index:0 count:2
2020-11-23T12:17:00.847 [Information] Count:2
2020-11-23T12:17:00.854 [Information] Executed 'GetForumTopics' (Succeeded, Duration=138ms)
```

The log above results in code 200 and a dataset as expected

```
2020-11-23T12:14:05.133 [Information] Executing 'GetForumTopics' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', )
2020-11-23T12:14:05.962 [Information] index:0 count:20
2020-11-23T12:14:11.318 [Information] Count:10
2020-11-23T12:14:11.319 [Information] Executed 'GetForumTopics' (Succeeded, Duration=6220ms)
```

The log above results in code 500 and no data (the response body is empty).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you say _"no data"_ do you mean that there's no response body with the 500 error, or that you're not getting the expected data? I'd definitely check to see if there's a response body of any kind, since it might give you clues as to what's wrong.

Comment: With no data I mean the response body is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out it was related to a cycling dependency in my EF model. Amazingly it worked in my unit tests, but failed doing JSON serialising